# Resume from suspend without waking up hd

Tags: suspend, power-management, disk

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on my Laptop with two hard disks. The primary one is a SSD, whereas the second one is a spinning hard disk.
Most of the time I don't need the second hard disk, I just use it for some larger files like movies etc.. Hence I send it to sleep with 'hdparm -Y /dev/sdb'.

However after resuming from suspend the hard disk is switched on again, which is quite annoying...
Does anyone know a solution to avoid waking up the second hd?

Thank you,

Leon

Comment: Thank you. But I would like to avoid unnecessary spin-ups to increase the lifetime of my disk.

Answer (score 0):

I would send the suspend command to the drive on resume.

under /etc/apm/resume.d/
you can add a script that does that.

it would probably look like this

```
 #!/bin/sh
 # sleep drive when resuming


 case "$1" in
   resume) /sbin/hdparm -Y /dev/sdb;; 
 esac
```